# Multiplying two numbers by finding out the greatest and lesser value

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

I am using a Little Man Computer simulator program called visible virtual machine to learn the basics of coding in assembly language format. Currently I am trying to multiply any two numbers (`x` & `y`) but in an efficient way by grabbing the greatest number and adding to it how many times the lesser number is equal to. How can I swap the numbers so it takes the greatest number and adds how many times the lesser number is equal to?

For example

The input can be either:

`5 * 12` or `12 * 5`

Efficient calculation:

`12 + 12 + 12 + 12 +12 = 60`

Not efficient:

`5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 60`

Code:

```
IN 
STO 99
IN 
STO 98 
STO 96
LDA 99
SUB 97
STO 99
LDA 96
ADD 98
BRP 07
LDA 96
OUT 96
*95
DAT 001
HLT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the command listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer#Commands), it looks like you could achieve this by subtracting the first input from the second and then use conditional branching to see which is the greater. Something like this:

```
     INP       // Get input into accumulator
     BRZ QUIT  // If zero, we're finished
     STA A     // Accumulator to A
     INP       // Get input into accumulator
     BRZ QUIT  // If zero, we're finished
     STA B     // Accumulator to B
     SUB A     // Subtract A from accumulator (B)
     BRP LOOP  // Jump to LOOP if B > A already, otherwise swap
     LDA A     // Put A into accumulator
     STA TEMP  // Accumulator to TEMP
     LDA B     // Put B into accumulator
     STA A     // Overwrite A with B
     LDA TEMP  // Put TEMP (A) into accumulator
     STA B     // Overwrite B with A: now B > A
LOOP LDA AB    // Put result into accumulator (starts off as zero)
     ADD B     // Add larger input to accumulator
     STA AB    // Update result
     LDA A     // Put loop counter (A) into accumulator
     SUB ONE   // Decrement
     STA A     // Update loop counter
     BRZ DONE  // Jump to DONE if loop counter is zero
     BRP LOOP  // Jump to LOOP if loop counter is positive
DONE LDA AB    // Put result into accumulator
QUIT OUT       // Output
     HLT       // Finish
ONE  DAT 1     // ONE = 1
A    DAT       // First input
B    DAT       // Second input
AB   DAT       // A * B
TEMP DAT       // Temporary (needed for swap)
```

Note that this is completely untested, so it's highly possible that it contains a bug! However, I've commented the source, so you can see the idea.

---

**EDIT** Turns out there are no bugs -- not bad for a stab in the dark ;) Anyway, the following is the slightly modified syntax that runs on the [Java-based simulator](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24821.0) mentioned in the comments:

```
      INP       // Get input into accumulator
      BRZ :QUIT // If zero, we're finished
      STA :A    // Accumulator to A
      INP       // Get input into accumulator
      BRZ :QUIT // If zero, we're finished
      STA :B    // Accumulator to B
      SUB :A    // Subtract A from accumulator (B)
      BRP :LOOP // Jump to LOOP if B > A already, otherwise swap
      LDA :A    // Put A into accumulator
      STA :TEMP // Accumulator to TEMP
      LDA :B    // Put B into accumulator
      STA :A    // Overwrite A with B
      LDA :TEMP // Put TEMP (A) into accumulator
      STA :B    // Overwrite B with A: now B > A
LOOP: LDA :AB   // Put result into accumulator (starts off as zero)
      ADD :B    // Add larger input to accumulator
      STA :AB   // Update result
      LDA :A    // Put loop counter (A) into accumulator
      SUB :ONE  // Decrement
      STA :A    // Update loop counter
      BRZ :DONE // Jump to DONE if loop counter is zero
      BRP :LOOP // Jump to LOOP if loop counter is positive
DONE: LDA :AB   // Put result into accumulator
QUIT: OUT       // Output
      HLT       // Finish
ONE:  1         // ONE = 1
A:    0         // First input
B:    0         // Second input
AB:   0         // A * B
TEMP: 0         // Temporary (needed for swap)
```

Comment: This is really great help. Everything seems to be correct but when running it there is error in `Line 2 cannot be interpreted`. Address map: `01: ERROR! --> BRZ QUIT`

Comment: Honestly: No idea! I mocked this up looking at the instruction set on Wikipedia; I don't have an LMC assembler to debug this. I'm sure you get the basic premise of the algorithm, though :)

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted the answer. If you have time, here is an online simulator that I tested the code: [HERE](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24821.0)

Comment: If you look at that applet's help, you'll see it uses a slightly modified syntax to that codified on the Wikipedia page. See my edit for that flavour, which turns out to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, you have gone the extra mile to help me. One last request: It works in that applet mentioned above. But in class we are using the software Visible Virtual Machine and I still cant get it to work there with the modifications. [HERE](http://www.cba.uri.edu/vvm/) is the page of that simulator, it requires installation.

Comment: This is left as an exercise! You won't learn anything by me changing the flavour of the syntax so it works in whatever assembler you're working with. As a hint: I've never used VVM, so the approach I would take is to look at the documentation and, preferably, some example code and try to match things up. It's a simplified assembly language, so it's not a hard task. For example, in my original, the labels are naked, whereas in the Java applet, it's looking for a colon (i.e., `LOOP` vs. `LOOP:`); similarly for referencing memory (`TEMP` vs. `:TEMP`), etc... Experiment :)